# Ralink rt3090 Wireless 802.11n drivers acting goofy in Slackware 14.0

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers

To begin with, my laptop (Lenovo b575) has been able to successfully connect to WEP and WPA2 networks within the last several days, but performance has been iffy. When the interface *did* work the connection would randomly drop out. Now it doesn't work at all.

meet my `$uname -a`:

`Linux computer 3.2.29 #2 SMP ... x86_64 AMD E-350 Processor AuthenticAMD GNU/Linux`

Running Slackware 14.0.

`lspci -v`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device f101
        Flag: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
        Memory at e0100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/32 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX
        Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
```

Okie doke. Let's
`lsmod | grep rt`:

```
Module        Size  Used by
rt2800pci     9372  0
rt2800lib    39864  1 rt2800pci
rt2x00pci     4914  1 rt2800pci
rt2x00lib    34972  3 rt2x00pci,rt2800lib,rt2800pci
...
```

Shouldn't `rt2800pci` be in use? Hmm... perhaps if I
`$dmesg | grep rt2800`

```
...
[  441.680783] rt2800pci 0000:03:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 18 (level, low) -> IRQ 18
[  441.680881] rt2800pci 0000:03:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[  441.685577] Registered led device: rt2800pci-phy0::radio
[  441.685633] Registered led device: rt2800pci-phy0::assoc
[  441.685689] Registered led device: rt2800pci-phy0::quality
[  441.755754] cfg80211:    (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 2683.758342] phy0 -> rt2800pci_mcu_status: Error - MCU request failed, no response from hardware
```

Hello... That last line out of `dmesg` seems like a good clue. A little [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=rt2800pci_mcu_status%3A+Error+-+MCU+request+failed%2C+no+response+from+hardware&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)ing leads me to believe that I may have some conflicting drivers.  How do I find out which ones I should think about blacklisting? My research has yielded some (seemingly) conflicting opinions on which driver is most appropriate for my kernel release and network controller.

Help me to understand, StackOverlords!

**===============================UPDATE===================================**

As per Henrik's suggestion, I've attempted to blacklist the rt2800pci driver in place of the rt2860sta driver.  However....

`#find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -name rt2860sta.ko`

Yields no results. I presume this means that the rt2860 driver isn't included in the Slackware 14.0 iso, yes?

Comment: I have no experience from that chipset myself, but googling "rt2800pci_mcu_status: Error - MCU request failed, no response from hardware" suggests that it might help to use the rt2860sta kernel module instead and blacklist rt2800pci.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this page?  http://blog.nielshorn.net/2011/08/rt3090-wireless-adapter-with-slackware-13-37/

Helped with my rt3090 issues

Comment: Link-only answers have no value when the link breaks or is unavailable.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reference.  Thanks.